# How to find substring in a string and return a new string with a number of characters surrounding the substring - Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

First of all I am new to javascript.

My question:

let's say I have a string like this

```
var str = "John Doe in the name used for people with no identity";
```

I need a function with 3 arguments something like

```
pullSubstring(text, string, number)
```

It will return a new string like this

```
*length of the number in strings* + string + *length of the number in strings*
```

To be more specific here's an example :

If I call the function like this

```
pullSubstring("for", "John Doe in the name used for people with no identity", 5)
```

the result will be like `"used for peop"`.

Comment: what is that argument number for? Is it 4 in above example you mentioned

Comment: Do your research before asking questions. Could start on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Methods_unrelated_to_HTML).

Comment: What in case if there are multiple occurences of same key string, 
unclear !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
function pullSubstring(searched,text,bordersLenght) {
    var idx = text.indexOf(searched);
    if (idx == -1 )
        return "";

    var startFrom = idx-bordersLenght;
    var endAt = idx + bordersLenght + searched.length;

    if (startFrom < 0)
        startFrom=0;

    if (endAt > text.length-1)
        endAt = text.length-1;

    return text.substring(startFrom,endAt);

}
```

You have to choose what to return when the searched string is not found (my function return an empty string), or when adding n character before or after the found text will take you before the start or after the end of text (my function trim the returned text in these two cases).

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I was trying to do